# GitHub shows banner: ... repository doesn't contain the 'none' path in 'master'

Tags: github

As title. Recently GitHub keeps showing me a banner complaining that one of my Repo. seems to have some problem. Does anyone know what would cause this warning? And how to disable it?

The only clue I have is that this usually happened when I force push some commits to the repo.

[image]

Comment: Mine: _The 'Mechazawa/BlockBlockAdBlock' repository doesn't contain the 'BlockBlockAdBlock.user.js' path in 'master'._

Answer (score 1):

Had the same warning since upgrading our GitHub Enterprise to `3.6.3` on one of our repos.

Turns out that one of the files within the repo contains a reference to a file which is no longer in the master branch.  For me, it was simply that the readme was pointing to an image file which was no longer present.  Where you have 'none', mine had reference to an `svg` file.  If you do a text search for 'none' you might find where the problem is.

The fix was is to simply remove the reference to the missing file or re-add it back to the affected branch.

**EDIT**
Looks like the official GHE v3.6.x [release notes](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.6/admin/release-notes) have now been updated to include the following which I believe is the cause of this experience:

> Following an upgrade to GitHub Enterprise Server 3.6 or later, existing inconsistencies in a repository such as broken refs or missing objects, may now be reported as errors like invalid sha1 pointer 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000, Zero-length loose reference file, or Zero-length loose object file. Previously, these indicators of repository corruption may have been silently ignored. GitHub Enterprise Server now uses an updated Git version with more diligent error reporting enabled. For more information, see this upstream commit in the Git project.